# Find whether a given number is a perfect square or not

Tags: c, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel

I am trying to find whether a given number is a perfect square or not by using just addition and subtraction.

Please review my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int check(int);
main()
{
    int N;


    printf("\n Enter the N:");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    if(check(N))
    {
        printf("\n[%d] Perfect Square:\n",N);

    }

    else
    {

        printf("\nNot perfect Square\n");

    }
}
int check(int n)
{
    int i=1;

    while(n>0)
    {
        n-=i;
        printf("[%d]",n);
        i+=2;
    }
    if(n==0)
        return 1;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Applying proper formatting to your code would be a good first step.

Comment: Since this is C++, you could use a proper `bool` and the check at the end simplifies to `return n == 0;`

Comment: There is nothing C++ in this code, so I am going to remove that tag.

Answer (score 14):

**Presentation**

I have re-indented your code, I do not know how your code is on your side but you should definitly indent it properly.
Also, you should remove useless lines.

**Naming**

`check` is not a good function name. `isPerfectSquare` would probably be easier for everyone to understand.

**Documentation**

Is it a good habit to add some documentation telling what your code is supposed to do. In your case, it could be nice to also tell the reader how it works.

> The expression for the nth square number is n2. This is also equal to the sum of the first n odd numbers.

**Types**

You can use the bool type in C++.

Answer (score 7):

Your code should only be 26 lines long. Most of the empty lines in your code are unnecessary.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static bool isPerfectSquare(int n) {
```

I changed the return type to `bool`, since the function either returns `true` or `false`.

```
  int i = 1;

  while (n > 0) {
    n -= i;
    i += 2;
  }
  return n == 0;
}
```

I also removed the `printf` statement, since that has been only for debugging. Instead of leaving these statements in the code, you should write unit tests.

```
int main(void) {
```

I changed the return type to `int`, since that is the required return type since the year 1989.

```
  int n;

  printf("Enter the number: ");
```

There should not be an extra newline and space in front of the word `Enter`. But there should be a space behind the colon.

```
  if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
```

When the `scanf` fails, the program should not continue.

```
    if (isPerfectSquare(n)) {
      printf("The number %d is a perfect square.\n", n);
    } else {
      printf("The number %d is not a perfect square.\n", n);
    }
```

I changed the text messages, so that they don't contain unnecessary brackets. You wrote a colon at the end of the line, which suggests that some text follows. That was misleading, so I removed it.

```
  }
  return 0;
}
```